# "Template is missing" install error on non-child theme

Tags: themes, local-installation

I understand the first comment in `style.css` dictates the difference between original theme and child theme.

Using the following simplest example is throwing the "Themes must have a stylesheet and a template ... Template is missing" error:

```
/*
Theme Name: Test
Theme URI: http://www.test.com
Description: Test install
Author: Test
Version: 1.0
Tags: Test
*/
```

File structure inside of `themes` directory:

```
themes
   -twentythirteen
   -test
      -css
         -style.css
      -index.php
```

The css seems to parse correctly and has line breaks making each entry in the comment distinct. I've tried creating multiple themes, all with the same result. The default themes are loading fine. Running this locally using MAMP, wp version 3.7.1.

Pulling my hair out here... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `style.css` out of `/css` and into the Theme's root folder.

Comment: Argh! That's what I get for being impatient. Any reason why wp requires it outside of a nested folder? Is there a way to keep the directory "tidy"?

Comment: Primarily, that's just where WordPress looks. It needs those header comments first, to identify the Theme as a valid Theme, and it only looks in the Theme root folder for `style.css`.